# array_map and array_unique technique corrupting json data to app

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode, multidimensional-array

I have a simple app that sends a query to a web db and returns a result set.  The App worked fine until I added a line of code to protect against duplicates in the multidimensional array before forming the json response. The only code I changed is in the php file on the server, not in the app.

Here is the before code which works fine, app doesn't crash or throw errors:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    array_push($resultArray, $row);
}
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

and here is how I changed it

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    array_push($tempArray, $row);
}
// remove any duplicates
$resultArray = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $tempArray)));
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

this php code removes duplicates from a multidimensional array in a test php file with no problem.  why is it corrupting my json and crashing the app?  Is there a better way to remove duplicate entries from a multidimensional array?

here is text of the error in xcode debugger

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($tempArray, $resultArray)` to compare the before/after versions?

Comment: the code you showed does not produce a multidimensional array. it will be an array of objects ?!

Comment: Without knowing exactly what is going on, let me guess: you refactored the code, changed the array-names, but missed to initialize an empty array with name `$tempArray`. This will cause `array_push` to produce a warning when the first element is not an array, leading to a malformated json output.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'll check it out tonight and let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MarkB and dognose for the helpful comments.  Here is the solution.

var_dump revealed that the array_map function worked as desired and removed duplicates. however, json sent to the app had missing index keys.

changing

```
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

to

```
echo json_encode(array_values($resultArray));
```

fixed the error and app runs again without duplicates in the result set.